# Numerals separated by hyphens

Tags: svg

I came across an [SVG optimizer](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) optimizer online that rounds off path coordinates.

The bezier path coordinates take a strange numbering format, with single numerals separated by hyphens. The first coordinate is a normal number, but the rest are special.

```
m161 141c7 0 7-5 5-7-2-2-2-7 5-7 7 0 7 5 5 7-2 2-2 7 5 7 3 0 9-1 9-1 0 0 1 6 1 9 0 7-5 7-7 5-2-2-7-2-7 5 0 7 5 7 7 5 2-2 7-2 7 5 0 3-1 9-1 9 0 0-6-1-9-1-7 0-7 5-5 7 2 2 2 7-5 7-7 0-7-5-5-7 2-2 2-7-5-7-3 0-9 1-9 1 0 0-1-6-1-9 0-7 5-7 7-5 2 2 7 2 7-5 0-7-5-7-7-5-2 2-7 2-7-5 0-3 1-9 1-9 0 0 6 1 9 1z
```

What is this number format called?

Comment: So then, whitespace followed by a hyphen is just extra whitespace. Commas also seem to be optional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Commas and whitespace are optional in paths. Therefore 7-5 should be interpreted as 7 followed by -5.

The [rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) is pretty much consume what you can till you get to something that can't be part of the current token, then start a new token.